# Sprite's Boundingbox in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

We used below code to get sprite's collision area in cocos2d.

```
CGRect heroRect = [heroBird boundingBox];
if(CGRectContainsPoint(heroRect, bullet.position))
```

How to get boundingBox in sprite-kit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SKSpriteNode *heroBird;
heroBird = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"heroBird.png"];
//heroBird rect can be set to whatever you like, shapes,rects,circles
heroBird.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:heroBird.size];  
// set heroBird collision, category and contact bitmasks
// detect using didBeginContact method


CGRect heroRect = heroBird.frame;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following line to get the bounding box:

```
CGRect heroRect = [heroBird calculateAccumulatedFrame]
```

see also [Apple Docu](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/calculateAccumulatedFrame)